# Reset line endings in the working directory when *enabling* core.autocrlf

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

Regarding `core.autocrlf` and working directory line-endings, I am seeing some strange, asymmetrical behavior when checking out files from the index.

When *disabling* auto-crlf, the following works as expected:

```bash
git config core.autocrlf # true
git config core.eol # crlf
git clone <repo_url>
cd <repo>
git config core.autocrlf false
git checkout . # Updated N paths from the index.
```

However, the inverse is not true. The following does not reset line-endings.

```
git config core.autocrlf # false
git config core.eol # crlf
git clone <repo_url>
cd <repo>
git config core.autocrlf true
git checkout . # Updated 0 paths from the index
```

How can I reset working directory line endings in the enable case? Is there a reason for this asymmetry that I'm not seeing, or is this a bug?

Comment: Sorry, not a direct answer, but I found configuring line endings via `.gitattributes` to be *massively* superior to trying to find and enforce the "correct" setting for `core.autocrlf`, because once it's set up it applies to **all** clones of that repository independent of any local configuration of the git client. Moving to that approach has basically eliminated all headache related to line endings. (And the subjective part: we standardize to LF line ending for everything except for file types that specifically need CRLF like .bat or .cmd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the enable-case, you must execute `git reset --hard`, as opposed to the disable-case, where you can just run `git checkout .`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reset working directory line endings in the enable case?

As I mentioned in "[Git: how to renormalize line endings in all files in all revisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309)", since Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you would use `git add --renormalize .` (instead of `git rm --cached -rf .; git add .`)

I would recommend using [`.gitattributes` directives](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion) only (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75577929/6309)), and keep `core.autocrlf` to `false`, as [I have always recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/6309).

Comment: just curious: isn't there also a `git update-index` hocus pocus formula to rerun content through git filters ?

Comment: @LeGEC After re-reading [torek's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73579300/6309), not that I know of.

Comment: @VonC I tried this using git version 2.30.2 and it did not work. Here is the script I'm using to test: https://gist.github.com/skurhse/e6f0bd539cb43f7f14d66210856e0911

Comment: @srage Then I would use gitattributes directives: they are more precise and reliable.